# Migrating application from MS Access 2003 to 2010 ODBC link table issues (Delete statement)

Tags: vba, ms-access, oracle11g, odbc

I am trying to migrate a MS Access application from MS Access 2003 to MS Access 2010.

The application connects to Oracle using ODBC also link tables to Oracle. The application is accessed using Citrix environment.

The issue we are facing is in SQL Delete statement from MS Access, it's not deleting the records properly and leaving one or two records in the oracle table. We tried lot of forums but we didn't get any help from any. The same statements are running fine if we execute in ORACLE directly.

Its a straight Delete * from table_name statement. We are trying to delete all the records from the table.

Comment: How you did it? What about truncate statement?

Comment: This is the error I was getting when I use the truncate table. "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'TRUNCATE TABLE tp007_multi_locs'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly"

Comment: How do you do it? DAO, ADO? If it's a stored query what is type? Can you show example?

Answer (score 0):

So after trying for days I found an alternate way of doing the same thing. which is working but, I wrote an select statement and did a delete on the recordset something like below.

```
Set dbs = CurrentDb
    DoCmd.Hourglass True
Set wrkdefault = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
strSQL = "Select * FROM tp007_multi_locs"
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    If rs.EOF Then GoTo ExitHere
    wrkdefault.BeginTrans
Do Until rs.EOF
    rs.Delete
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
    wrkdefault.CommitTrans
rs.Close
dbs.Close
```

I don't have any explanation of why "Delete * FROM tp007_multi_locs" is not working.